# Transposing rows to columns using self join

Tags: sql, ms-access, transpose

I have a table named category with values as below,

CategoryId      | Value |      Flag

1                          25                a

2                          26                a
3                          27                a

1                          28                m
2                          23                m

1                          36                p
2                          33                p

Now I want to transpose the rows present in this table to columns based on the flag, something like

CategoryId      | aValue |      mValue   |      PValue
1                          25                28               36

2                          26                23               33
3                          27                null              null

I am trying to join based on the category id but I am just getting the matched records (inner join) in my resultset even if I use left outer join in my query.

My query:

```
SELECT 
  A.CategoryId, 
  A.Value AS actual, 
  B.Value AS projected, 
  C.Value AS Manual
FROM ((a AS A left JOIN b AS B ON A.categoryid=B.categoryid) 
  left JOIN c AS C ON A.categoryid=C.categoryid) 
WHERE (((A.flag)="a") and ((B.flag)="p") and ((C.flag) ="m"))
```

I am getting the proper results if I have the data in 3 different tables.

I just want to check what would be the best way to transpose a rows to column when using self join...

Thanks,
Barani

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT CategoryId, 
       MIN(SWITCH(YourTable.Flag = 'a',Value)) AS aValue,
       MIN(SWITCH(YourTable.Flag = 'm',Value)) AS mValue,
       MIN(SWITCH(YourTable.Flag = 'p',Value)) AS pValue
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY CategoryId
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks a lot for your reply, this solution works flawlessly in MS ACCESS. Does this query work in Oracle or Sybase?

Thanks,
Barani

Comment: No, I believe `SWITCH` is MS-ACCESS exclusive. For Oracle or Sybase, you have to use `CASE` statement

Comment: Any use of Switch() tends to be a red flag to me, as it looks like you're storing data in your SQL statement (i.e., it's a way of getting by without a join to a lookup table).